# Error o errores básicos al hacer prácticas de validación en formulario

Tags: javascript, formularios, validación

Estoy haciendo pruebas nuevas en un proyecto aparte bien para terminar uno que realizo a la par del curso y bien para ver si aprendo al 100% la matería de este curso, sin embargo en un simple ejemplo hay algo que no me sale.

archivo de prueba -> **javascript.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="es">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">

        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0"><!-- /*TEMPORAL PARA EL MENÚ NUEVO O VIEJO*/ -->

        <meta name="author" content="José Carlos" />

        <meta name="description" content="Practicas y proyectos realizados en php, POO, MVC, javascript, html5, css3" />

        <meta name="keywords" content="proyectos, realizados, php, POO, MVC, javascript, html5, css3" />

        <title>Plantilla de Mis proyectos en PHP</title> 


        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://localhost/mis-proyectos-php/vistas/js/usuarios.jsvistas/css/principal.css"> 

    </head>
    <body>  

    <!-- <form method="post" action="algo.php" onsubmit="return registroUsuario()" class="form-login-registro"> -->

        <form method="post" onsubmit="return registroUsuario()" class="form-login-registro">

                    <div id="alertaPrueba">     <!-- Temporal para la respuesta javascript -->              

                        <span class="form-login-registro">* EMAIL:</span>
                        <input type="text" name="regEmail" size="30" maxlength="50"  placeholder="E-mail" class="input-login-registro input text" id="regEmail" />  <!-- Cambiado temporalmente a type=text para hacer pruebas de javascript             -->    

                    </div>


                        <span class="button-form-registro"><input type="submit" value="REGISTER"  class="input submit" /></span>

                    </form>

                    <script src="http://localhost/mis-proyectos-php/vistas/js/usuarios.js"></script>
```

```
    </body>
    </html>
```

archivo javascript -> **usuarios.js**

```
/*=============================================
    VALIDAR EL REGISTRO DE USUARIO
    =============================================*/

    function registroUsuario(){ 

        /*=============================================
        VALIDAR EL EMAIL
        =============================================*/

        var email = $("#regEmail").val();

        if(email != ""){

            var expresion = /^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,4})+$/;

            if(!expresion.test(email)){

                $("#regEmail").parent().before('<div class="alert alert-warning"><strong>ERROR:</strong> Escriba correctamente el correo electrónico</div>')

                return false;

            }

        }else{  

            $("#regEmail").parent().before('<div class="alert alert-warning"><strong>ATENCIÓN:</strong> Campo obligatorio: email.</div>')

            return false;
        }

        return true;

    }
```

¿Qué estoy haciendo mal? No me reconoce el campo vacío ni tampoco el error de poner mal el email.

Saludos.

Comment: Acabo de probar tu codigo y si funciona.  Te falta incluir la libreria jQuery?

Comment: Concuerdo con @alanfcm , tienes que incluir <script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

Comment: Gracias a los dos, acabo de editarlo y ya funciona perfectamente añadiendo esta parte al código.

<script src="http://localhost/mis-proyectos-php/vistas/js/plugins/jquery.min.js"></script>

¿Cómo puedo daros puntuaciones positivas?

Gracias a ambos, un saludo.

Comment: Pon tu comentario como respuesta, y aceptala. Saludos.

Comment: Ok, gracias de nuevo @alanfcm

Comment: Gracias @Luciano Montañez

Answer (score 0, accepted):

acabo de editarlo y ya funciona perfectamente añadiendo esta parte al código.

```
<script src="http://localhost/mis-proyectos-php/vistas/js/plugins/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Gracias a ambos por vuestra ayuda.

Comment: debes marcarla como aceptada

Comment: ¿Ya está marcada? Perdón por mi ignorancía, aún me faltan cosas para aprender a manejarme en esta web y este mecanismo. Saludos.

Comment: Si , ya quedó marcada!